# Why am I not getting a warning by my compiler, although I've added these compiler options in tasks.json?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, warnings

I am using VSCode and have followed this tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

In my `tasks.json` file, I have added the two command line arguments `"-Wall"` ,`"-fsanitize=undefined"` and `-fsanitize=address`.

The file looks like this now:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-Wall",
                "-fsanitize=undefined",
                "-fsanitize=address",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run the simple piece of code below, I do not get any warning, although I'm trying to access the element at index 3 of a vector with size 1. What do I have to do in order to get a warning/error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a(1);
    std::cout << a[3];
}
```

Comment: You could always add this error check to your code review checklist.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/er9Gxf) - I also recommend adding `-fsanitize=address` which will catch the problem in runtime.

Comment: I now see that only the very latest version of `g++` warns about the out-of-bounds access. 10.2 doesn't warn, but the trunk version does at goldbolt.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks. According to the tutorial (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), I need Mingw (http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/start), but under that link only g++ Version 8 is included. What can I do?

Comment: I think you'll have to go for Nathans answer and use `at()` to get exceptions. A compiler can only catch simple out-of-bounds errors so it's not something one can rely on even if you get the newer `g++` version. Just think about if you get some user input that should be used as an index. The compiler could never catch that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you. Do you think I can at least expect a warning from VSCode, when I run the code in Debug-Mode? Because I'm not getting that either.

Comment: @Ruirui If you debug compile your program (and add `-fsanitize=address`) I'm pretty sure that you'll get a nice dump when doing what the program in the question does. I don't think VSCode has anything to do with whatever happens though. It's afaik an editor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok, that's weird. Because I'm only getting `-1414812757` as output.

Comment: @Ruirui What does `g++ --version` report? `g++ 8.1` [seems to dump it nicely](https://godbolt.org/z/1naTnh)

Comment: @TedLyngmo It reports `g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`. Can it be VSCode's fault? Or where do you think must the problem lie?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just ran `g++ -Wall -fsanitize=address  Aufgabe4.cpp -o Aufgabe4.exe` in CMD (so no VSCode) and this was the output: `C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lasan
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to guarantee a warning or error for out of bounds access of a vector.

What you can do though is switch from using `[]` to using `at` like

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a(1);
    std::cout << a.at(3);
}
```

which will generate an exception at run time and you can write code to handle that exception.

Comment: isn't there any possibility to guarantee an out of bounds error by using compile flags (when using `[]`)?

Comment: @Ruirui AFAIK, no.  That's too much work for the compiler.  For cases where you have a local array, and you are using a compile time value, a compiler can warn, but a vector doesn't have a known compile time size of elements and so it's much harder to analyze the code.  This is why `at` exists or you always put a check on access to make sure the index is valid.